# Get User in Office 365 by ImmutableId

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory

1. I am looking to get the Office 365 User details based on his ImmutableId. However there is no direct attribute to supply the ImmutableId and hence only way currently is to supply it in where-object on the Get-MSOLUser. However this would loop through all users and hence is not a good solution. So is there any other way?
2. I am trying to build a tool that will read the Users in On-Prem AD and do some licensing work on O365. There could be multiple AD's and hence I started looking at ImmutableId to uniquely identify a user. Is using 'ImmutableId' the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However this would loop through all users and hence is not a good solution. So is there any other way?

The ImmutableId was generated when sync the on-premise AD with Azure AD.

ImmutableId = user.ObjectGUID.toBase64String()

```
$guid = [GUID]"{UserObjectId in on-premise AD}"

$bytearray = $guid.tobytearray()

$immutableID = [system.convert]::ToBase64String($bytearray)
```

The ImmutableId is mainly used for AD sync, we are not able to query user via ImmutableId.

> There could be multiple AD's and hence I started looking at ImmutableId to uniquely identify a user. Is using 'ImmutableId' the correct approach?

If you use the Microsoft Azure AD Sync to sync the user, you will find the database file "ADSync.mdf" under dir "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\Data". There is table named "mms_metaverse", you can find the mapping here.

```
SELECT
[object_id],
[userPrincipalName],
[cloudAnchor] AS [CloudUserId],
[cloudSourceAnchor] AS [ImmutableId]
FROM
mms_metaverse
```

[image]

UPDATE#1:

After some research, I found that the Graph API is able to filter the user by ImmutableId.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=onPremisesImmutableId+eq+'zYGi36Y8tkCwX4lYBb8bUA=='
```

Comment: So the reason I raised the query was specifically when you have multiple directories being synced against. Assuming sync is already defined and working, I am reading from a specific On-Premise AD Group that contains a subset of users. The UPN's in the AD Vs what's there in the cloud could be different due to consolidation to a single domain in cloud. If I have to query the cloud either I replicate the mapping logic applied in the mapping tool or I could use the ImmutableId. Looks like at this point there is no way to use ImmutableId and I should consume the mapping logic in my tool too.

Comment: @Nitin, I did more research and found that the graph API could be a possible solution. See my UPDATE#1

Comment: Interesting! Let me have a look at that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in using C# with the Microsoft.Graph library to query MS Graph for a user using ImmutableID here is a snippet on how to do that:

```
var filter = Uri.EscapeDataString($"onPremisesImmutableId eq '{immutableIdString}'");
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter(filter)
    .Select("id")  // Add in whatever properties you need to extract here
    .GetAsync();

if (users.Count >= 1)
{
    // ... code ...
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"No user with immutable ID {immutableIdString} was found in Azure AD");
}
```

Note the use of `Uri.EscapeDataString` to escape special characters in the filter query. I was having trouble with `+` characters throwing things off.

Note: I used System.DirectoryServices module to perform a search of on premise and extracted the ImmutableID from the AD object's GUID using this:

```
Guid objectGuid = new Guid(objectGuidString);
var byteArray = objectGuid.ToByteArray();
string immutableId = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

Hope this helps someone out there.